# How to reset a dictionary in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Ok, so this question is a little hard to explain, but I'll do my best to ask it. So basically I have a dictionary with room names on it, and every time you run the game, the dictionary shuffles and outputs a random room, and if you beat the room you get a point. If you beat every room you go to the boss level. Basically, every time you beat a room the room gets deleted from the dictionary so that you don't have to replay the room. But if you die, then I want it so that the dictionary resets and basically the whole game resets. See, if I die, and choose start over, the room is already deleted from the dictionary, therefore I can't replay it. Is there a way that I can somehow reset the dictionary every time I die?

Comment: Any option I can think of uses a second dictionary. Keep track of deleted items in a second dictionary or keep a second dictionary that holds all items that you can just make a copy of once you need to reset.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries do not keep a history, when you remove keys from a dictionary you can't later on 'reset' it. You'd have to just *recreate the dictionary* or create a copy *first*.

To do either, you need to

- Put the definition of the dictionary in a function, and each time you need to start, call the function to create the dictionary again.
- or create a copy with `dict.copy()` every time you start a game, so you have a fresh dictionary to edit. Delete keys from the copy, not the original.

Personally, I'd not edit the dictionary. I'd create a *list* of all the room names (the keys of the dictionary) instead, then shuffle this list once and take the last value from it each time you need a random room, with `random.shuffle()` and `list.pop()`.

This has two advantages:

- No need to create the dictionary any more. You now create a new list instead. (Not that big an advantage). It's basically like the 'create a copy first' option above, but the copy is smaller.
- You only have to shuffle once. A shuffled list gives you rooms in random order too, and makes sure you don't get duplicates either. Lists have order and *stay* shuffled, while dictionaries do not.

That'd look like this:

```
# new game
roomnames = list(roomdescriptions)  # copy the names of the rooms dictionary
random.shuffle(roomnames)

# picking the next room
if not roomnames:
    # reaching the boss level!
else:
    # take the next random room name, and get the room description for it
    nextroom = roomdescriptions[roomnames.pop()]
```

Comment: can you give me an example on recreating the dictionary or creating a copy please? I'm new to programming so I'm trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Actually nevermind. I ended up doing .update(added copy of dictionary here) and every time the player died and decided to start over, I would do the update function. Thanks for the help though, I really appreciate it!